# Set dynamically mat-menu content

Tags: typescript, angular6, angular-material-6

I have a angular6 material mat-table, one of columns contains button triggering mat-menu. I want it to display different options depending of {{server.status}} column value. How can I do that?

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="status">
   <mat-cell *matCellDef="let server"> {{server.status}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
   <mat-cell *matCellDef="let server"> 
        <mat-icon [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="clickable">more_vert</mat-icon>
         <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
                 <button mat-menu-item>
                      <span>Optionset1</span>
                 </button>
         </mat-menu>
         <mat-menu #menu="matMenu2">
                 <button mat-menu-item>
                       <span>Optionset2</span>
                 </button>
         </mat-menu>
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I did it. I used *ngIf statement. I'll put it here for anyone looking for answer

```
                <div *ngIf="server.status == 'ONLINE'">
                    <mat-icon [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="clickable"></mat-icon>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="server.status == 'OFFLINE'">
                    <mat-icon [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu2" class="clickable" ></mat-icon>
                </div>
                <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
                    <button mat-menu-item>
                        <span>Option1</span>
                    </button>
                </mat-menu>
                <mat-menu #menu2="matMenu">
                    <button mat-menu-item>
                        <span>Option2</span>
                    </button>
                </mat-menu>
```